# use of try catch on the main of a big application

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I have a application with many classes. This application is started on the main with a sinle line, let's say something like this:

```
   int main()
    {
      try
      {
          classA.start();
      }
      catch(...)
      {
          std::cout<<"EXCEPTION CAUGHT"<<std::endl;
      }
    }
```

After `classA.start()` is called, then other classes and other procedures are called. If there's any unexpected exception ocurring on those classes, the `try-catch`, as stated in the code above, wont catch them. I was trying and seems that I need to set `try-catch` on every place I think it can be a exception. My point here is, since I already cover most of the exception, I want to add this global `try-catch` to handle those I forgot and be able to log it and keep working.

I hope I explained myself properly.

Thanks

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: "_the `try-catch`, as stated in the code above, wont catch them_" Please provide [mcve], that shows that such `try-catch` won't catch `throw`n exceptions.

Comment: You seem to have global variables in your program (classA for instance). Your code won't catch exceptions in the constructors of global variables. But it should catch everything else. You certainly do not need to set try catch everywhere.

Comment: @john if on the method `start()` from `classA` I define a `int m = 5/0;` no exceptions are catched....

Comment: @Capie That's because `5/0` does not throw an exception

Comment: @Capie: Integer division by zero is undefined behaviour. See my (pukka) answer.

Comment: @john what about this? `class Polymorphic {virtual void member(){}};`
`Polymorphic *pb =0;
    typeid(*pb);`  this should throw `std::bad_typeid` but its also not catched

Comment: @Capie That's UB I think (quote - When applied to an expression of polymorphic type, evaluation of a typeid expression may involve runtime overhead (a virtual table lookup), otherwise typeid expression is resolved at compile time. ) What happens if you try `throw "something"`? As usual what we really need is a complete program that illustrates the behaviour you are complaining about.

Comment: @Capie `*pb` is a null pointer dereference causing Undefined Behavior. You should also distinguish between C++ exceptions and other exceptions (for example on windows there are SEH exceptions that let you handle things like invalid memory access).

Comment: So, is there any way to catch undefined behaviour?

Comment: No, it is a programmer's responsibility to ensure that his program does not contain any undefined behaviors. This is one of those things that make programming with C++ so difficult.

Comment: @Capie To catch UB at the site, which invokes it? No. The code, due to undefined behavior, could just silently corrupt memory. How would one detect if memory modification was done due to UB, or defined behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this will indeed catch every *exception* thrown within your program (when `main` is in the call stack), but that doesn't necessarily include any *undefined behaviour*, for example

1. out of bounds array access.
2. invalid pointer dereference.
3. stack overflows.
4. an integer division by zero.

To repeat, exceptions thrown when objects with `static` storage duration are destructed, or global objects constructed or destructed will not be caught at your catch site either.

Comment: Yes, and one notable exception is that if you are using SEH, catch(...) does catch SEH exceptions, and this covers things like access violations.

Comment: @MikkelK.: Indeed. Hence my "necessarily" in my answer.